# PyCharm and Oracle Connection: Accessing the tables

Tags: python, oracle, pycharm, cx-oracle

So I've successfully connected to my Oracle database on pycharm via Database feature. (Using Pycharm 2019.3) How do I use a table from that database on my python code / file?

For your reference I successfully did this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt3C8ecMzk0

Next step: Use a table from there on my python file.
I've been looking at ways on how to link a table on my python file but literally can't find any on the pycharm documentations or youtube vids. The normal cx_oracle chunks works but it doesn't make sense to repeat the same connections again via code when it's already connected on pycharm database? How do I link it without having to go through this?

```
#This code works but doesnt make sense to connect again 
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

conn_usr = u'Username'
conn_pw = u'Password'
dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("hostname","1521","rwhwp0")

# Connecting to the Oracle server
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user = conn_usr, password = conn_pw, dsn= dsnStr)
def read_query(con, query):
    cursor = con.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute( query )
        names = [ x[0] for x in cursor.description]
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        return pd.DataFrame( rows, columns=names)
    finally:
        if cursor is not None:
            cursor.close()

users_df= read_query(con, """ SELECT * FROM USERS""" )
```

Comment: Are you just trying to read from a second table? e.g. `other_df = read_query(con, """select * from MY_TABLE""")`

Comment: I'm just trying to read the tables from the connected database. (Youtube link attached of how database is connected) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt3C8ecMzk0

Comment: Are you sure that every call for the **cursor** from `read_query` function is closed at the end?